# Is there a way to post JSON file to an API?

Tags: javascript, api, browser, console

I have got a javascript code that runs locally in the browser. It looks for a particular part of the DOM tree and stringify(s) it. I can manually copy the file from the console.
I was wondering if there was a way to post that file to an API without any manual work.

Comment: Do you know http?

Comment: you can just parse the scripts output to post it to an api, apparently you don't know much about how http requests work, i recommend [reading this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/index.htm)